# JSF multi messages support not working

Tags: jsf, redirect, message

I've been using this approach ([Persist and pass FacesMessages over multiple page redirects](http://www.ocpsoft.org/java/persist-and-pass-facesmessages-over-page-redirects/)) in my application and it has been working fine.
Recently, the application was heavily changed and now the messages are no longer showing up. I tried to compare the source code, but there are just too many differences.
Looking at the log, it seems that the messages are only being added after `MultiPageMessagesSupport` finishes processing, and are lost with the redirect:

```
[#|2017-01-23T09:23:18.321+0000|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1||_TimeMillis=1485163398321;|
  SAVING MESSAGES RESTORE_VIEW 1|#]

[#|2017-01-23T09:23:18.331+0000|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1||_TimeMillis=1485163398331;|
  SAVING MESSAGES RESTORE_VIEW 1|#]

[#|2017-01-23T09:23:18.333+0000|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1||_TimeMillis=1485163398333;|
  SAVING MESSAGES RENDER_RESPONSE 6|#]

[#|2017-01-23T09:23:18.333+0000|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1||_TimeMillis=1485163398333;|
  RESTORING MESSAGES RENDER_RESPONSE 6|#]

[#|2017-01-23T09:23:23.571+0000|INFO|glassfish 4.1||_TimeMillis=1485163403571;|
  [ERROR] ecc_src - Failed to access the WSDL at: http://epms:10130/endpoint?wsdl. It failed with:
                Connection refused: connect.|#]

[#|2017-01-23T09:23:23.571+0000|SEVERE|glassfish 4.1||_TimeMillis=1485163403571;|
  MESSAGES ADDED AT PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6|#]
```

I've tried comparing the usual suspects (`faces-config.xml, web.xml, filters`), but can't find anything that justifies this change of behavior.
Can someone give me some hints on what should I be looking for?

**EDIT #1**

Following @Kukeltje suggestion, I've double checked all external components and noticed that Omnifaces' version was different (currently 2.5.1, previously 2.0). Switching back to version 2.0 was enough to make the issue go away.
I'll investigate further and check in which version of Omnifaces this behavior has changed (I'll try versions 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 and 2.4).

**EDIT #2**

It works fine with Omnifaces' versions 2.1 and 2.2 and stops working from versions 2.3 and on.

Comment: Changes just in your code? Or also newer JSF version/impl? Other new external component suites? Utility frameworks? Can you create a [mcve]  that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Kukeltje, just in code. I've a server configured with 2 domains, each with a different version of the application (but sharing everything else) and the issue is just happening in one of the domains.

Comment: @Kukeltje, you're right. I've double checked all the changes and noticed that omnifaces library is different (2.0 vs 2.5.1). I've switched back to version 2.0 and the issue is no longer occurring.

Comment: @Kukeltje, do you wish to put your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Hmm... imo it would be better to slightly 'improve' your question to explicitly include omnifaces in it and the version, so it either can be fixed in 2.5.x or that a better answer can be created that states why it does not work (anymore)...

Comment: I can answer my own question and explain that changing omnifaces' version solved the issue. Do you agree?

Comment: You could, but I would not. What I meant was is that just downgrading is not a real solution, so maybe it solves your operational issue and is the cause of the difference in behaviour, but it does not explain why it does not work with a newer version of OmniFaces. It is a workaround or limitation in upgrading. Knowing in detail why it fails would most likely be something @BalusC can only answer quickly. Finding out for me would take too much time. But again, a real [mcve] would be needed to find the real cause.